# Get an Integer's value by using a String containing the Integers name

Tags: c#, string, variables, int

I have tried:

```
    int counter14 = 0;
    int counter13 = 0;
    int counter12 = 0;
    int counter11 = 0;
    int counter10 = 0;
    int counter9 = 4;
    int counter8 = 0;
    int counter7 = 0;
    int counter6 = 0;
    int counter5 = 4;
    int counter4 = 0;
    int counter3 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    // Test for four-of-a-kind

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 14; i >= 2; i--)
    {
        sb.Append("counter").Append(i.ToString());

        if ((FindName(sb.ToString()) as int).Equals(4)) // Problem line here
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have four-of-a-kind!");
        }
        sb.Clear();
    }
```

...but unfortunately unsuccessful.

How am I able to access the Integer in this way and check it's contents?

Many thanks.

Comment: why dont you use Array? http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-array

Comment: And to answer your question. no its not possible at all because local variables will not get compiled by name.

Comment: Oki, I see. Using an array did not even cross my mind, thank you @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: I think in JavaScript it works. Use the eval() function there.

Answer (score 0):

this is done by several ways that are listed belows

> 1st Method

```
int counter14 = 0;
        int counter13 = 0;
        int counter12 = 0;
        int counter11 = 0;
        int counter10 = 0;
        int counter9 = 4;
        int counter8 = 0;
        int counter7 = 0;
        int counter6 = 0;
        int counter5 = 4;
        int counter4 = 0;
        int counter3 = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;

        // Test for four-of-a-kind

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 14; i >= 2; i--)
        {
            sb.Append("counter").Append(i.ToString());

            if (sb.ToString().Contains('4')) // Problem line here
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have four-of-a-kind!");
            }
            //sb.Clear();
        }
```

> 2nd method

```
 int counter14 = 0;
        int counter13 = 0;
        int counter12 = 0;
        int counter11 = 0;
        int counter10 = 0;
        int counter9 = 4;
        int counter8 = 0;
        int counter7 = 0;
        int counter6 = 0;
        int counter5 = 4;
        int counter4 = 0;
        int counter3 = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;

        // Test for four-of-a-kind

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 14; i >= 2; i--)
        {
            sb.Append("counter").Append(i.ToString());

            if (sb.ToString().Contains("14")) // Problem line here
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have four-of-a-kind!");
            }
            //sb.Clear();
        }
```

I don't understand why you used

```
if (sb.ToString().Contains("14"))
```

condition in for loop?

any ways from mine perspective you can do this by Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, int> counter = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        counter.Add("counter14", 0);
        counter.Add("counter13", 0);
        counter.Add("counter12", 0);
        counter.Add("counter11", 0);
        counter.Add("counter10", 0);
        counter.Add("counter9", 4);
        counter.Add("counter8", 0);
        counter.Add("counter7", 0);
        counter.Add("counter6", 0);
        counter.Add("counter5", 4);
        counter.Add("counter4", 0);
        counter.Add("counter3", 0);
        counter.Add("counter2", 0);
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //for (int i = 14; i >= 2; i--)
        foreach(string str in counter.Keys)
        {
            //sb.Append("counter").Append(i.ToString());

            //if (sb.ToString().Contains("14")) // Problem line here
            if(counter[str]==4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have four-of-a-kind!");
            }
            //sb.Clear();
        }
```

or simply from the List

```
List<int> counter = new List<int>();
        counter.Add(0);
        counter.Add(0);
        counter.Add(0);
        counter.Add(4);
        counter.Add(0);
        counter.Add(0);
        counter.Add(0);
        counter.Add(4);
        counter.Add(0);


        //for (int i = 14; i >= 2; i--)
        foreach(int value in counter)
        {
            //sb.Append("counter").Append(i.ToString());

            //if (sb.ToString().Contains("14")) // Problem line here
            if(value==4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have four-of-a-kind!");
            }
            //sb.Clear();
        }
```

Dictionary is used because i don't have idea, if you want counter number for records? else List is best option, or if you know the exact amount of your data you can also used array type.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should use some kind of collection for the counters and filter on that.

Here's the solution using an array:

```
var counters = new[] {0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };

// Test for four-of-a-kind
foreach (var matchingCounter in counters.Where(counter => counter == 4))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have four-of-a-kind!");
}
```

Comment: @Dhani Kris Frohling did this answer your question? If so please mark as answer :-)